# Get a histogram using a date vector

Tags: r, histogram

I'm working on [this](https://www.kaggle.com/nguyenhoc/plane-crash) data set using R and I'm trying to show the number of incidents each year.

Using R's help pages, I wrote:

```
getData=read.csv('planecrashinfo_20181121001952.csv')
attach(getData)
lct <- Sys.getlocale("LC_TIME"); Sys.setlocale("LC_TIME", "C")
getData$date<-as.Date(date, format='%B %d, %Y')
```

That works, but using

```
hist(date, "years", format= '%Y')
```

results in

> "Error in hist.default(date, "years", format = "%Y") : 'x' deve essere numeric".

Is there a package I am not using?

Comment: use `hist(lubridate::year(getData$date))`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest using `lubridate` for date fields:

```
library(readr)
library(lubridate)
library(ggplot2)
getData <- read_csv("planecrashinfo_20181121001952.csv")
getData$date <- mdy(getData$date)
hist(year(getData$date))
```

Or with `ggplot`

```
ggplot(data = getData , aes(x = year(date))) + 
  geom_histogram(binwidth = 1)
```